# Why does Visual Studio not pull GIT tags?

Tags: git, visual-studio

We use GIT tags to identify our version releases, but always have to use the command line pull to pull the tags locally. Why does the Visual Studio pull not pull GIT tags?

Comment: ... ... ....because they didn't code that?

Comment: The default pull behavior pulls them. Wouldn't they have had to actively exclude them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "GIT labels"? Git has *tags*, which are like branch names but (a) stuck in a global name-space and (b) never supposed to change, and also "notes".

Comment: Sorry, I meant tags